# Problem using replaceWith to replace HTML tags with BeautifulSoup on Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup in Python and am having trouble replacing some tags. I am finding `<div>` tags and checking for children. If those children do not have children (are a text node of NODE_TYPE = 3), I am copying them to be a `<p>`.

```
from BeautifulSoup import Tag, BeautifulSoup

class bar:

 self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.input)
 foo()
 def foo(self):    
  elements = soup.findAll(True)

  for node in elements:

    # ....other stuff here if not <div> tags.

    if node.name.lower() == "div":
      if not node.find('a'):
        newTag = Tag(self.soup, "p")
        newTag.setString(node.text)
        node.replaceWith(newTag)
        nodesToScore.append(newTag)
      else:
        for n in node.findAll(True):
          if n.getString():  # False if has children
            newTag = Tag(self.soup, "p")
            newTag.setString(n.text)
            n.replaceWith(newTag)
```

I'm getting an AttributeError:

```
  File "file.py", line 125, in function
    node.replaceWith(newTag)
  File "BeautifulSoup.py", line 131, in replaceWith
    myIndex = self.parent.index(self)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I do the same replacing on `node` higher up in the for loop and it works correctly. I'm assuming it's having problems because of the additional iterating through node as n.

What am I doing wrong or what would be a better way to do this? Thanks!
PS. I'm using Python 2.5 for Google Appengine and BeautifulSoup 3.0.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

```
    myIndex = self.parent.index(self)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

This code occurs on line 131 of BeautifulSoup.py.
It says that `self.parent` is None.

Looking at the surrounding code shows that `self` should equal `node` in your code, since `node` is calling its `replaceWith` method.(Note: The error message says `node.replaceWith`, but the code you posted shows `n.replaceWith`. The code you posted does not correspond to the error message/traceback.) So apparently `node.parent` is None.

You could probably avoid the error by placing

```
if node.parent is not None:
```

at some point in the code before `node.replaceWith` is called.

Edit: I suggest you use `print` statements to investigate where in the HTML you are when `node.parent` is None (i.e. where the error is occurring). Maybe use `print node.contents` or `print node.previous.contents` or `print node.next.contents` to see where you are. Once you see the HTML it might become obvious what pathological situation you are in which is causing `node.parent` to be `None`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the `node.replaceWith` vs the `n.replaceWith`. I added the additional code where that is referenced. The `if not` runs fine when the `else` is not present which is why I thought it wasn't relevant but I was wrong.

Comment: @feesta: This is hard to debug without seeing the HTML. I've added an edit (above) suggesting how you might be able to find the HTML which corresponds to the problem.

Comment: @~ubuntu Thanks! it is working now!
I added `if node.parent is None: (log node) else: (the rest)` I found the bad HTML was `div` tags with only whitespace. That is part of what I'm stripping out.
Thanks again!

Comment: @feesta: Ah yes! That's a good way to debug it; better than my suggestion. Two thumbs up :)