# How to select only parent if child is already container in Beautiful Soup findall?

Tags: python, html, tree, beautifulsoup

How can I make BeautifulSoup select only the parent , if the child is already contained in the search results ? I dont want child to be selected again due to my logic which might replace the parent tag .

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
        my_span_tags = soup.findAll('span', myattrib=re.compile(''))
        #Loop all span tags
        for each in my_span_tags:
            #replaceWith or replaceWithChildren as per requirement
```

HTMLexamples

```
 <span myattrib="1"> Foo </span> works fine . 

 <span myattrib="1"> Foo <span myattrib="1"> Foo </span> </span>
```

is going to cause be trouble when I am doing some operation on the child , because the parent has changed for example and it throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index' . There is a question on that specific error : 
[Problem using replaceWith to replace HTML tags with BeautifulSoup on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461814/problem-using-replacewith-to-replace-html-tags-with-beautifulsoup-on-python)

My question is how to exclude children if parent is already selected in BS ?

Currently the selection would look like a Python List:

```
[<span myattrib="1"> Foo <span myattrib="1"> Foo </span></span>(Parent with Child),<span myattrib="1"> Foo </span>(Child)]
```

Notice the repetition which I would like to avoid ?

Answer (score 0):

If your current selection, selects the `children`, then you can use the [`.parent`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-up) method, in BeautifulSoup to get the parent of the current item selected.

Comment: Current selections selects both parent (with child container) and child seperately

Comment: Can you show me your whole HTML and your code. This seems to be very limiting to work with.